# Изменить надписи у label по нажатию на button

Tags: c#, алгоритм, visual-studio, asp.net

есть 3 шт. label с надписями
для label1 - привет
для label2 - старт
для label3 - коровка

при нажатии на button, должно происходить изменение надписи у label1 c "привет" на " * "
т.е. нужно нажать 3 раза по очередно на button, чтобы на форме изменились все надписи для трех label'ов на " * " а не сразу на всех.

Код:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = textBox1.Lines.Length.ToString() + " * ";
}
```

Код:

```
Forms Code
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int t = 0;
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
           String[] ss = new String[6] {"Коровка", "Привет", "Старт""};

             label1.Text = ss[t];
             t++;
             if (t > 5)
                 t = 0;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyForm : Form
{   
    Button bt;
    Label lb1, lb2, lb3;

    public MyForm()
    {
        bt = new Button() {Text = "Im on step 1", Width=150};
        this.Controls.Add(bt);

        bt.Click+=Button_Step1;

        lb1 = new Label() {Text = "Im label 1", Top = 20};
        this.Controls.Add(lb1);

        lb2 = new Label() { Text = "Im label 2", Top = 40 };
        this.Controls.Add(lb2);

        lb3 = new Label() { Text = "Im label 3", Top = 60 };
        this.Controls.Add(lb3);
    }


    private void Button_Step1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        button.Click-=Button_Step1; 

        lb1.Text = "Step 1 passed";
        button.Text = "Im on step 2";

        button.Click+=Button_Step2;
    }

    private void Button_Step2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        button.Click -= Button_Step2;

        lb2.Text = "Step 2 passed";
        button.Text = "Im on step 3";

        button.Click += Button_Step3;
    }

    private void Button_Step3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        button.Click -= Button_Step3;

        lb3.Text = "Step 3 passed";
        button.Text = "Im on step 1";

        button.Click += Button_Step1;
    }
}
```

[image: ...]

Comment: реально интересное решение ))))

Comment: Простенький конечный автомат

Answer (score 0):

и так один из вариантов решения это завести переменную счетчик и отслеживать её (если нет еще как либо условий), например:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int StepButtonClik = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (StepButtonClik == 0)
        {
            label1.Text = " * ";
            StepButtonClik++;
        }
        else if (StepButtonClik == 1)
        {
            label2.Text = " * ";
            StepButtonClik++;
        }
        else
        {
            StepButtonClik = 0;
            label3.Text = " * ";
        }
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Для установки надписей на LableN
        label1.Text = "Hello";
        label2.Text = "start";
        label3.Text = "КОРОВА!";
    }
```